# Remove values from DropDownList

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

```
$("#Month option:selected").val()
```

this is giving me a selected value from my dropdownlist. But i want to remove or hide some options in my dropdownlist can i do with the help of this?

```
$("Day option").value("31").empty();
```

is it valid or not. Please give me solution.

```
    function ValidatefuneralDate() {
    var today;
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
    var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;  
    var day = currentDate.getDate();
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("en-US") > -1) 
    {
        today = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
        var selectedDate = $("#Month option:selected").val() 
        +'/'+$("#Day option:selected").text() + '/' + 
        $("#Year option:selected").text();
    }
    else 
   {
        today = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
        var selectedDate = $("#Day option:selected").
        text() + '/' +   $("#Month option:selected").
        val() + '/' + $("#Year option:selected").text();
    }
    if ($("#Month option:selected").val("2"))
    {
        $("#Month option[text='31']").hide();
        $("#Month option[text='30']").hide();
        $("#Month option[text='29']").hide();
    }
    if (selectedDate < today) {
        $("#lblFeneralDate").html('@Html.
        R(VirtualPath, "ValidatefuneralDate")');
        return false;
    }
    else { return true;}
   }
```

This is my jquery function and

```
<div class="DDLabel">
Day:@Html.DropDownList("Day", new SelectList(new List<object>
{
                                        new { value =1, text = "1"},
                                        new { value =2, text = "2"},
                                        new { value =3 ,text ="3"},
                                        new { value =4, text = "4"},
                                        new { value =5, text = "5"},
                                        new { value =6, text = "6"},
                                        new { value =7, text = "7"},
                                        new { value =8, text = "8"},
                                        new { value =9, text = "9"},
                                        new { value =10, text = "10"},
                                        new { value =11, text = "11"},
}, "value", "text", 1), 
new { @onchange = "e_date_changed();", @style ="width:66px" })
```

This is DDL for days from 1 to 31 like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.remove()` to completely remove element from DOM.

```
$("#Month option[value='whatever']").remove();
```

**EDIT**

```
$("#Month option[value='whatever']").hide();
```

and you can later get them back by

```
$("#Month option[value='whatever']").show();
```

Comment: Sir both r hiding the values ?

Comment: if ($("#Month option:selected").val() == "2")
        {
            $("#Month option[value='31']").remove();
            $("#Month option[value='30']").remove();
            $("#Month option[value='29']").remove();
        }. is it correct i want if user selects feb. then other DDL should display only 28 days. mens days according to months

Comment: </div>
 <div class="DDLabel">
 Day:@Html.DropDownList("Day", new SelectList(new List<object>
 {
   new { value =1, text = "1"},
    new { value =2, text = "2"},
  new { value =3 ,text ="3"}, Code is something like this

Comment: Please update the code in the question itself. It is not readable here,

Comment: You should do  `$("#Month option[value='31']").hide();
        $("#Month option[value='30']").hide();
        $("#Month option[value='29']").hide();`

Comment: Replace `text` by `value`.

Comment: sir i have already used this .......it was not working thats y i m trying with text.

Comment: Okay try once `$("#Month option[value=31]").hide(); ` i.e. without `' '`

Comment: Was the .remove() removing the options?

Comment: Sir nothing was happening.......take a look on if condition.                                                                                                     if ($("#Month option:selected").val("2"))     is it right?

Comment: Ohho, you are mistaken their only `if($("#Month option:selected").val() == 2)`

Comment: any thing wrong in this if condition? i think may syntax is wrong                      if ($("#Month option:selected").val()=="2")    is it right?

Comment: Yes what i gave you in the above comments is right. you used it?

Comment: sir we were doing some mistake v r removing months but we want to remove days.............now it is working thanx 4 ur support. i hope in future u ill also help me.

Comment: Selector is day on the place of month.

Comment: Sir after removing the value how can we regain it?

Comment: Don't remove the value instead `.hide()` it and when you want to regain just do `.show()` on the same selector

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute equal selector to target element by value and the use `.remove()` to remove or `.hide()` to hide the element:

```
$("#Month option[value='33']").remove();
```

or

```
$("#Month option[value='33']").hide();
```

Comment: actually i have 2 DDL Month and Day. According to the selected month.....the value in Day DDL should be change. EXA-- feb = 29 Days, June=30 Days and July = 31 Days...........this is my prob.

Comment: can you elaborate more on this.

Comment: there is 2 dropdowns Month and Day. According to selected value in Month DDL i want to change the values of Day DDL. Day DDL has 31 days in HARD CODED.

Comment: if ($("#Month option:selected").val() == "2") { $("#Month option[value='31']").remove(); $("#Month option[value='30']").remove(); $("#Month option[value='29']").remove(); }. is it correct i want if user selects feb. then other DDL should display only 28 days. mens days according to months –